# How to clear all submission data from a single wffm form

Tags: wffm, sitecore-client

I have a task to remove all current submission data from a particular form. We're running Sitecore at 8.1. I can't seem to find an interface that Sitecore provides to do this. I remember at 7.2 you could view individual form submissions through form reports but that seems to be gone with 8.1. Is this going to require a sql script?

Let me know, thanks!

Comment: Are you using WFFM in CMSOnly Mode (i.e storing it in SQL) or Mongo DB?